# How do I record a voice using the MediaStream Recording API in react?

Tags: reactjs, record, voice, mediastream

Two problems have occurred.

1. The first recording is blob size:0, and it is not recorded like the picture.
   It works from the second recording.

[image]

2. The second recording is also delayed by one blob.
   For example, if i recorded in the order of A, B, and C, recording and playing B that i recorded before will play A, and recording and playing C will play B.

What part of my code is the problem?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { IoMicCircle } from 'react-icons/io5';

function TestRecordingVoice(): JSX.Element {
    const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [media, setMedia] = useState<any>();
    const [chunks, setChunks] = useState<Blob[]>([]);
    const [audioURL, setAudioURL] = useState<string>('');

    const onRecord = () => {
        if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
            navigator.mediaDevices
                .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
                .then((stream: any) => {
                    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                    console.log(mediaRecorder.state);

                    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (e: any) => {
                        setChunks((prevChunks) => [...prevChunks, e.data]);
                    });

                    setMedia(mediaRecorder);
                    setIsRecording(true);
                })

                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log('error');
                });
        } else {
            console.log('error');
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect_chunks', chunks);
    }, [chunks]);

    const offRecord = () => {
        if (media) {
            media.stop();
            const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });

            const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            // const audio = new Audio(audioURL);
            setAudioURL(audioURL);

            console.log('blob-off', blob);
            console.log(audioURL);

            setChunks([]);
            setIsRecording(false);
        } else console.log('failed making blob');

        console.log(media.state);
    };

    return (
        <Container>
            <RecordingButton onClick={isRecording ? offRecord : onRecord}>
                <IoMicCircle />
            </RecordingButton>
            {audioURL && (
                <AudioPlayer>
                    <audio src={audioURL} controls />
                </AudioPlayer>
            )}
        </Container>
    );
}

const Container = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 28rem);
    margin: 0 auto;

    @media screen and (max-height: 750px) {
        position: relative;
        top: 4rem;
    }
`;

const RecordingButton = styled.button`
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 10rem;

    svg {
        color: #f44336;

        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
`;

const AudioPlayer = styled.div`
    margin-top: 2rem;
`;

export default TestRecordingVoice;
```